# IllegalStateException when starting Thread 2nd time by user

Tags: java, android, multithreading, illegalstateexception

I am building a simple messanger app for android and have some issues with sending a textmessage. 
First Time I use my OnlickListener the message is sent and displayed in my listview. When i try it a second time in the activity my app crashes with an IllegalStateException.

I dont really know much about threading and here is the only time i need to restart a thread by clientside

Here is the part of code i have trouble with

```
    sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Keine Nachricht zum versenden 
vorhanden");
                return;
            } else {
                if(!threadTextMessage.isAlive())
                    threadTextMessage.start();
            }
        }
    });


    threadTextMessage = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String name = filesystem.readFileLine("usr.txt", 0);
            String password = filesystem.readFileLine("usr.txt", 1);
            //benötigter recipient ist Instanzvariable
            String mimetype = "text/plain";
            String data = editText.getText().toString();

            try {
                message = post("http://palaver.se.paluno.uni- 
due.de/api/message/send", buildJson(name, password, recipient, mimetype, 
data));
                System.out.println("Sende Nachricht:< {\"Username\":\"" + 
name + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"Recipient\":\"" + 
recipient + "\", \"Mimetype\":\"" + mimetype + "\", \"Data\":\"" + data + 
"\"}");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        editText.getText().clear();
                    }
                });

                threadTextMessage.interrupt();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("-----" + e.toString() + "------");
            }

        }
    });
```

Can anybody suggest me what i should do

Comment: "*Can anybody suggest me what i should do*" - Please add the full stack tace and highlight the line throwing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can not start a Thread twice. First time you start your thread and interrupt it at the end. But a the second time you call the start() method at the same object as before. You need to create a new Object everytime you want to start a thread. Even though i´m a bit confused that the "isAlive()" does not prevent the error, this should be the problem.

So in your case:

```
    threadTextMessage = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String name = filesystem.readFileLine("usr.txt", 0);
            String password = filesystem.readFileLine("usr.txt", 1);
            //benötigter recipient ist Instanzvariable
            String mimetype = "text/plain";
            String data = editText.getText().toString();

            try {
                message = post("http://palaver.se.paluno.uni- 
due.de/api/message/send", buildJson(name, password, recipient, mimetype, 
data));
                System.out.println("Sende Nachricht:< {\"Username\":\"" + 
name + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"Recipient\":\"" + 
recipient + "\", \"Mimetype\":\"" + mimetype + "\", \"Data\":\"" + data + 
"\"}");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        editText.getText().clear();
                    }
                });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("-----" + e.toString() + "------");
            }

        }
    });
```

this creation has to be done everytime before starting the tread. Or better put that in a own class, so you just have to create a object of it.
But remove the interupt() call or otherwise you could have 10 Threads waiting after creating 10 objects. Let the threads finish!

Comment: Forgot to tell to remove the interupt() call. Important!